# What does it mean in Groovy to specify a property followed by a closure?

Tags: gradle, groovy, syntax

I am completely new to Groovy, trying to learn it, but stymied because I can't parse the syntax well enough to even know where to look in the documentation.  I am using Groovy in Gradle.  There are many places where examples are given, but no explanation on what it means, so I just need a few pointers.

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'com.xxx.yyy'
            artifactId = 'zzz'
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal();
    }
}
```

The main build code is referring to things on the project class.  On that class, I can find a property called publishing, and it is a class  `PublishingExtension`.   It appears then that the curly brace starts a closure with code in it.  The documentation says this syntax:

```
publishing { }
```

configures the `PublishingExtension`. What I want to understand is what it means (i.e. what is actually happening) when I specify what looks like a property and follow that with a Closure.  In the Groovy documentation I could not find any syntax like this, nor explanation.  I sure it is something simple but I don't know enough to even know what to look for.

If I visit the [Project Class API Docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) there is no method there named `publishing`.   Nor is there a property defined by the method `getPublishing`.  Apparently this magic capability is enabled by the `publishing plugin`.  If I visit the [Publishing Plugin API Doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/publish/plugins/PublishingPlugin.html) there is no description of this publishing property either or how it modifies the base project.

Similarly, drilling down a little more, that closure starts with a symbol `publications` and in the documentation for the `PublishingExtension` I find a property which is of type `PublicationContainer` which is read only.  I also find a method named `publications` which does not accept a closure, but instead a `configuration` of type `Action<? super PublicationContainer>`.  Again, I don't know how the contents of the curly braces are converted to an `Action` class instance.  How does this object get constructed?   `Action` is an interface, and the only method is `execute` however it is completely unclear how this action gets constructed.

The block that defines the Action starts with symbol `mavenJava` that looks like a method, but actually that first symbol is declaring a name of a new object of type `MavenPublication` named `mavenJava`.  Either this is magically constructed (I don't know the rules) or there is a method called, but which method?  What is it about `PublicationContainer` that allows it to know that an arbitrary `mavenJava` command is supposed to create an object instance.  Then again, the curly braces that follow this, is that a closure, a configuration, or something even more exotic?

So as you can see, I am missing a little info on how Groovy works.  So far I can't find documentation that explains this syntax, however it might be there if I knew what to look for.   Can anyone explain what the syntax is really doing, or refer me to a site that can explain it?

Comment: https://blog.mrhaki.com/2009/10/groovy-goodness-optional-parenthesis.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

[publishing](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:publishing(groovy.lang.Closure)) is called to configure the [PublishingExtension](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.publish.PublishingExtension.html).

In [PublishingExtension](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.publish.PublishingExtension.html) there is a `publications` method accepting an [Action](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Action.html) which is usually coerced from a Closure. In Groovy a Closure is automatically converted to an interface with a single method.

`mavenJava` is a non-existent DSL method, which is passed by Gradle DSL builder to  the `create` method of [PublicationContainer](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.publish.PublicationContainer.html):

```
publishing.publications.create('mavenJava', MavenPublication) {
    // Configure the maven publication here
}
```

`groupId` and `artifactId` are properties of [MavenPublication](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenPublication.html) and are being set here.

`from` is the `from(component)` of [MavenPublication](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenPublication.html) and is written using Groovy simplified method call literal without brackets.

In general Gradle uses a root DSL builder which calls the nested DSL builders provided by plugins. Hence sometimes it's difficuilt (also for the IDE) to find proper references of all parts of the build.gradle file.

Comment: How is a Closure converted to an Action?  Is there a canonical translation?  Is everything that starts and ends with a brace a Closure?  Is there a heuristic for finding out which of the various methods available are automatically invoked?  For example, is there a "create" method that is always available for use?  What method is called on the Publishing extension in order to configure it?

Comment: https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_closure_to_arbitrary_type_coercion closure coercin. Look, you should really start learning the basics. No one can explain you anything, if you are "completely new"

Comment: Yes, i think you are right.  Taking class today.  Thanks for the help.